# xsd schema validation

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, schema

I am having an issue with xsd schema. I have a following schema defined:

```
<xs:element name="nodes" type="nodesRootType" />

<xs:complexType name="nodesRootType">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="node" type="nodeType" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="nodeType">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="node" type="nodeType" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>
```

and I am testing it on following xml:

```
<label name="Label_6" >
    <label name="Label_7" />
</label>
<label name="Label_8" />
```

The error I am getting is :

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content 
    was found starting with element 'node'. One of '{node}' is expected.
```

What am I missign here. Any help is hightly appreciated.

Best,
Jozef

Comment: You might want to edit your question, I can't see the schema nor the xml.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  I can correctly serialize an XML of the form you want.  There are two parts to the fix:  1) moving maxOccurs and minOccurs to the correct location, and 2) defining the element separately, in one location, so it's obviously the same type at both schema locations.

Answer (score 3):

A single XML document that you are verifying cannot have multiple roots.  It must have a single root.  Your XML:

```
<label name="Label_6">
    <label name="Label_7"/>
</label>
<label name="Label_8"/>
```

has two roots because there are two "`label`" elements both at the root level.  Also, your schema does not define any element named "`label`" so I am confused.  You probably want a schema that will validate something like the following XML:

```
<labels>
    <label name="Label_6">
        <label name="Label_7"/>
    </label>
    <label name="Label_8"/>
</labels>
```

where here you have a single root "`labels`".  Note that you have elements with the same name, "`label`" at different levels in the hierarchy.  This isn't verboten (see, for example, xhtml where you can have a `div` inside a `div` inside ...) but it can be confusing.  For the sample XML shown above, try a schema something like:

```
<xs:element name="labels">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="label" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="labelType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="label" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="label" type="labelType"/>
```

Comment: Yes, I cut the xml example out of context. Sorry for that. 
You are correct, I want to validate exactly what you have written.

You said that I do not have 'label' element in the schema. Can you please provide a schema example for xml stated above?

Many thanks.

Comment: It is throwing same error. I found by trials that if I replace <xs:element name="label" type="labelType"/>
with
<xs:element ref="label"/>
in "recursive" complexType definition, it works ... 
I just do not know why is that...

Comment: I found your problem.  You have the minOccurs and maxOccurs in the wrong location.  Check out my edit above.  With this schema and sample XML, I am able to correctly serialize and deserialize.

Comment: Hi Eddie, may I ask you one more thing? Is it possible to check with schema some unique constrains? Let's say I want to have a name attribute of label element a unique name cross whole xml. Is it possible? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jozef:  Yes, use xs:unique to require uniqueness of values.  Check out http://books.google.com/books?id=QLZIR3zQfhoC&pg=PA284&lpg=PA284&dq=xs:unique&source=web&ots=vnqc8W2FgP&sig=VgZUSPw6Wthbn08qJ-D8Z7jFRrs&hl=en&ei=uZyUSc7IDojKNNXfqJYM&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=10&ct=result

Comment: @Jozef: If you try to get xs:unique to work and cannot, then you can always create a new question (rather than ask for help in comments).  That will allow people to create detailed answers.